# In place Downgrade Windows Server 2008 R2 from Standard to Web

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I mistakenly installed Server 2008 R2 as Standard, but my license key is only valid for Web.  Can I downgrade my current installation to Web without re-installing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, a reinstall is required

Answer (score 1):

The process to downgrade to Windows Web Server 2008 R2 to Windows Server Standard 2008 R2:

Open Windows Registry Editor:

Browse to HKLocalMachines > Software > Microsoft > Windows NT > Current Version > Edition ID

Then change the value from []Standard to []Web.

Then run the install DVD and run the downgrade. This worked for us.

Answer (score 0):

No. I believe you are warned about this when you choose the edition of the operating system to install.

Comment: Yea, but who ever reads those annoying little warning messages? ;-)